# angular 2 project created with angular-cli errors without any code chanegs

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I have an angular2 project created using angular-cli which was working without any problems. I added another developer to the team and he pushed some code to a branch.

All i did was switching to his branch to merge the code and then i came back to my own branch and did npm start again. My application was broke. This is the error i get now.

```
error_handler.js:48EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: self.selectOrCreateHostElement is not a functionErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:48(anonymous function) @ application_ref.js:236ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:232onInvoke @ ng_zone.js:238ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:231Zone.run @ zone.js:114(anonymous function) @ zone.js:502ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:265onInvokeTask @ ng_zone.js:229ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:264Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:401
error_handler.js:50ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: self.selectOrCreateHostElement is not a functionErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:50(anonymous function) @ application_ref.js:236ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:232onInvoke @ ng_zone.js:238ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:231Zone.run @ zone.js:114(anonymous function) @ zone.js:502ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:265onInvokeTask @ ng_zone.js:229ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:264Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:401
error_handler.js:53ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:53(anonymous function) @ application_ref.js:236ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:232onInvoke @ ng_zone.js:238ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:231Zone.run @ zone.js:114(anonymous function) @ zone.js:502ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:265onInvokeTask @ ng_zone.js:229ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:264Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:401
error_handler.js:54TypeError: self.selectOrCreateHostElement is not a function
    at DebugAppView._View_AppComponent_Host0.createInternal (/AppModule/AppComponent/host.ngfactory.js:13:21)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.create (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:63235:21)
    at DebugAppView.create (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:63435:44)
    at ComponentFactory.create (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:43674:36)
    at ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:28173:40)
    at http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:28082:89
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at PlatformRef_._moduleDoBootstrap (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:28082:42)
    at http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:28050:27
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:92501:26)ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:54(anonymous function) @ application_ref.js:236ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:232onInvoke @ ng_zone.js:238ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:231Zone.run @ zone.js:114(anonymous function) @ zone.js:502ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:265onInvokeTask @ ng_zone.js:229ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:264Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:401
error_handler.js:57ERROR CONTEXT:ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:57(anonymous function) @ application_ref.js:236ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:232onInvoke @ ng_zone.js:238ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:231Zone.run @ zone.js:114(anonymous function) @ zone.js:502ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:265onInvokeTask @ ng_zone.js:229ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:264Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:401
error_handler.js:58DebugContext {_view: _View_AppComponent_Host0, _nodeIndex: 0, _tplRow: 0, _tplCol: 0}ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:58(anonymous function) @ application_ref.js:236ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:232onInvoke @ ng_zone.js:238ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:231Zone.run @ zone.js:114(anonymous function) @ zone.js:502ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:265onInvokeTask @ ng_zone.js:229ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:264Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:401
zone.js:388Unhandled Promise rejection: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: self.selectOrCreateHostElement is not a function ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: ViewWrappedError {_nativeError: Error: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: self.selectO…, originalError: TypeError: self.selectOrCreateHostElement is not a function
    at DebugAppView._View_AppComponent_H…, context: DebugContext} TypeError: self.selectOrCreateHostElement is not a function
    at DebugAppView._View_AppComponent_Host0.createInternal (/AppModule/AppComponent/host.ngfactory.js:13:21)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.create (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:63235:21)
    at DebugAppView.create (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:63435:44)
    at ComponentFactory.create (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:43674:36)
    at ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:28173:40)
    at http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:28082:89
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at PlatformRef_._moduleDoBootstrap (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:28082:42)
    at http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:28050:27
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:92501:26)consoleError @ zone.js:388_loop_1 @ zone.js:417drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:421
zone.js:390Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: self.selectOrCreateHostElement is not a function(…)
```

This does not make any sense to me, because i have the same exact code running without any issues in another computer, where i did not switch branches. This looks and sounds silly but i have no idea why this is happening. I tried doing npm cache clear and cleared the browser cache assuming it has something to do with some ghost files from cache but i cant get rid of that error.

I can clone the exact state of the project in a different directory and that works. So any idea why something like this can happen. Is there a directory where angular-cli holds the temporary generated files for development server that i can clear?

Comment: What version of the CLI are you on? I had installed v1.0.0-beta.22-1, and rolled back (to beta.21) due to errors, with no code changes. First time I have had issues like that.

Comment: "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.18",
This is the version that I have in my package.json. I recently did NPM install when i added another module to my project. But i did not change the angular-cli version since the beginning of the project.